# What's the use of ssl certificate in firmware

Tags: security, ssl-certificate, iot

I found an SSL certificate when I decompiled a firmware of an IOT. I am curious what can pentesters do with this certificate?

Comment: The certificate could be for anything, but this being an IoT device, it could be a TLS certificate. If you can replace it, you could fake the authentication.

Comment: This is more a question for [security.se]. However, certificates are public, so the information in it is commonly useless. You can use the memory location if it is a trusted certificate to replace it; if they succeed they could e.g. fake firmware images or TLS - depends what the certificate is used for. Or if it is a certificate that is specific to the device, they may try and find the related private key using the information.